# Safe way to load url stored in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the safest way to load a url saved in database?

`window.open("<%=raw @post.url%>");`

Doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since window.open opens a link in new tab there is no direct way to instruct the browser form server side to open a link in a new tab.

But you can apply a little JS hack. In your erb file do it like.

```
<%= link_to "Post", @post.url, {:target => '_blank', :id => "linktoclick"} %>
<script>
   document.ready = function(){
     document.getElementById("linktoclick").click();
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the URL in your database/where are you going to use it?

Assuming @post.url will return the url you want, then something as simple as:

```
<a href="<%= @post.url %>">[awesome link name]</a>
```

html output would be:

```
<a href="http://your-stored-url.com">[awesome link name]</a>
```

Could you provide more information on where/how the url needs to be used?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% unless @post.url.blank? %>
  <%= link_to @post.url, 'http://' + @post.url, :target => '_blank' %>
<% end %>
```

You may want to use this. Unless checks if URL in database is empty or not. If URL is mandatory in database, you may want to remove that part.

Extra, if you need validation for url, you may want to use a validation something like this:

```
  URL = /\A(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?\z/
  validates :url,
            format: {with: URL, message: 'Invalid url format. Make sure you don\'t have http:// in your link'},
            allow_blank: true
```

So, user will input url without http://, and you will add that http:// in html, as I showed above.

Comment: well its not 'Invalid **email** format. Make sure you don\'t have http:// in your link'